# Change of Database for PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a concern about changing databases for PowerBI.
Currently I've implemented a "reporting" database which simply replaces bunch of large CSV files with relationships defined in a MySQL database, the database itself has no security measures in place.

If I want to redesign a PostgreSQL database with is more scalable and properly built, and when i change the data path to this new database. I am assuming as long as I have the same table and column names, the data model and visuals will preserve?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Correct - as long as you have the same table/column names, you should be good. You may have to redefine the relationships between the tables, but your visuals/measures/columns, should be good.